# Object created is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get a function to loop through data in two tables and put them into an object. The first for-loop that goes through the first table does this fine, but the second for-loop that goes through the second table spits out an empty object when there's only 1 row to go through. 
However, when there is more than 1 row, then all of the objects have the values as the *second* row.

I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong here:

```
function foo(){
    var rows = $('#table1').find('tr');
    var array1 = [];
    for(var i = 1; i < rows.length-1; i++){
        var row = $(rows[i]).find('input');
        var o = {
            name : $(row[0]).val(),
            bday : $(row[1]).val(),
            parent : $(row[2]).val(),
            parentBDay : $(row[3]).val(),
            parentNumber : $(row[4]).val()
        };
        array1.push(o);
    }

    var array2 = [];
    rows = $('#table2').find('tr');
    for(var j = 1; j < rows.length-1; j++){
        var row = $(rows[i]).find('input');
        var o = {
            name : $(row[0]).val(),
            bday : $(row[1]).val(),
            phoneNumber : $(row[2]).val()
        };
        console.log('wtf: ' + JSON.stringify(o));
        array2.push(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: You use `rows[i]` instead of `rows[j]`

Comment: what do you mean by `$(row[4]).val()`

Comment: And also why i and j are starting with 1 and not 0 ?

Comment: @MarounBaydoun probably first row it's header with th instead of td.

Comment: @jcubic True, you're probably right

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nu5dcpa7/1/

Comment: Guys, don't down-vote the op. He is clearly a beginner. All of us were beginners. Let us be good to him and understand his situation. His question is clear and he tried to write a code. What is the problem? Despite the fact that the question is not excellent, I am upvoting it to support beginners.

Comment: @LajosArpad +1 too for the same reasons.

Comment: @forgivenson  you were right. feel really dumb right now.

Comment: @jKo no worries, we've all made silly mistakes like that :)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your indexes in the for cycle are not looping well. You start the for cycle from `1`, which, in case you want to use the very first element, then it is wrong. Note, that indexing begins from `0`. If you miss the very first element on purpose, because it is a header row or something, then this is not a problem. However, the end sign, like

```
< rows.length - 1
```

is clearly wrong. Let's suppose, the number of rows is 50. Then its last index is 50 - 1 = 49. If you loop from one until you reach the number below 50 - 1, then your last index will be 48 and you will miss the very last element. Your condition should be either `< rows.length` or `<= rows.length - 1`.